# Angular2: what expressions can we interpolate in template

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I read that we can interpolate Javascript expressions. What is the list of valid Javascript expressions that we can interpolate? So far for interpolation I have a displayed property, eg. `object.property`, short expressions like `{{1+1}}` what else Javascript expressions can we interpolate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expressions in Angular2 are very similar to expressions in Angular in terms of the scope of what they allow.

JavaScript expressions that promote side effects are prohibited including

- Assignment (= +=, -=)
- Using the `new` keyword
- Chaining expressions using a semicolon or comma
- Increment (++) and decrement operators

Furthermore, there is no support for bitwise operators like `|` or `&`

Generally, it's a good idea to put complex JavaScript logic inside a controller or component, instead of inside a view. This is because of the `Separation of Concerns` design principle and making code more modular and readable.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-expressions

Comment: Your answer is correct, but he was asking for angular2 - aka, doc link is off.

Comment: Semicolons seem to be allowed in Angular 5, at least in (event)="" handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Angular 2 default pipes for evaluating the expression inside  an interpolation. Please refer the below link
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-pipes#sum