# angular template syntax error for a valid JS expression

Tags: javascript, angular, templates

That's a fragment of a template in my project.

```
<footer>
  © {{ (new Date()).getUTCFullYear() }} Company
</footer>
```

Funfact is that `(new Date()).getUTCFullYear()` is valid JS syntax. What is the reason for angular throwing error here?

That's the stacktrace/error:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 7 in [
  © {{ (new Date()).getUTCFullYear() }} Company
] in ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@20:8 ("
</main>

<footer>[ERROR ->]
  © {{ (new Date()).getUTCFullYear() }} Company
</footer>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@20:8
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:42542:34)
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:53033:19)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:66784:39)
    at http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:66708:62
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:66708:19)
    at createResult (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:66593:19)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:85093:26)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:84975:43)
    at http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:85363:57
```

Comment: Not all JavaScript expressions can be put into template expressions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38152650/4793951

Comment: @Zircon ok, so `new` being forbidden is the answer here. Thanks mate!

Comment: Store `(new Date()).getUTCFullYear()` in a variable in your component and then use it in your template. Anyway, I didn't know that you could not use `new` within the template, never tried it before. Thanks Zircon.

Comment: @SrAxi nothing I wouldn't think of...

Comment: @ducin By watching your profile I deduced it, but I also wrote this in case someone less experienced should face the same issue. :P